# Adding two audio files at a predefined SNR level

Tags: audio, noise, snr

I have two speech audio wav files. `file1` is primary speech, `file2` is supposed to be interference.

I want to add them so that the SIR (signal to interference ratio) is 10 dB.

- How do I proceed?
- Do I do sample by sample addition like below?

  Assuming $N$ is the data-length of both the files (single channel).

  ```
  for i = 1:N
     x = 0.1 * file1(i)^2 / file2(i)^2 
     file3(i) = file1(i) + x*file2(i)  
  end
  ```

  `file3` is the output file.
- Are there any better ways to do this?

Note: $\textrm{SIR(in dB) = 10 log (Power(signal) / Power(interference))}$

Comment: better first confirm what the different energies are of the two files.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson In one case they're about the same, -80 and -78 (I used this one liner to compute average energy `10*log(sum(data.^2)/length(data))`

Comment: well, assuming the interference file is the -80 dB file, then i would scale the interference file by $10^{-(10-2)/20}$ and add it to the signal file.  if the interference file is the -78 dB file, i would add 2 to the 10 rather than subtract.

Comment: This might be useful, sen is signal and noise is interference    signal_power = (1/length(sen))*sum(sen.*sen);
noise_variance = signal_power / ( 10^(SNR/10) ); 
Y = sen + sqrt(noise_variance)/std(noise)*noise(1:length(sen));

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson that works. thanks. my original approach was giving scratchy sound.